# Javascript check if a number is 0, 0.0,0.0000

Tags: javascript

AM currently processing gps coordinates in my javascript app using leaflet map and i would like to check if the value of longitude is 0,0.0,0.0000 since when my gps boots up sometimes it does send the first coordinates been 0 and later changes to the correct value

So sometimes the wrong values can be sent as 0 or 0.0 or 0.0000 that is 0 with zero decimal places

So currently i have added a quick check with

```
function initGpsMap(latitude, longitude){

  if(latitude != 0 || longitude != 0){
    //start processing map now
   }else{
    //show loading
   }
}
```

The above only checks if its not 0 but passes when the value sent is 0.0 how can i check for all zero values .Sometimes a valid longitude or latitude can be a value like 0.0122

so its some checks like `latitude or longitude doesnt have any no other than 0`. How do i add this so that if the value passed is 0.000000 still its detectected as zero

Comment: It's pretty easy because `0`, `0.0`, `0.0000` are all exactly the same number; literally the same pattern of bits in the computer.

Comment: Is `latitude` a string?

Comment: Yes its a string

Comment: So `if (+latitude === 0)` accounts for any "version" of 0.

Comment: Why does this matter to you?  Assuming you plan on doing any math, `0`, `0.0`, and `0.0000` are the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its for the map display i want to delay display of map untill a correct latitude and longitude is passed

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to numbers first, and then check to see if the numbers are `=== 0`:

```
function initGpsMap(latitude, longitude) {
  if (Number(latitude) === 0 && Number(longitude) === 0) {
    // both latitude and longitude are 0

    // show loading
  } else {
    // start processing map now
  }
}
```

Of course, if you prefer to use `+` instead of `Number`, that's a simple tweak:

```
if (+latitude === 0 && +longitude === 0) {
```

Comment: I prefer to use `Number` because it's more explicit. `+` works too, I just find it a bit harder to read in comparison